# Where is the /boot partition?

Tags: boot, hdmi, display

I'm trying to boot my pi running NOOBS, and my monitor's not displaying any input. After checking other similar problems, I was advised to place the lines hdmi_config=1 and hdmi_safe=1 in the config.txt file under the boot partition. Where is this file located? I'm looking for them on my PC, but I can't seem to locate the file or the partition.

Answer (score 1):

NOOBS has 3 partitions.  One is FAT, another FAT32 (which has the images) and an EXT4. The First is mounted as /boot when the OS is running. This is where you should find your files.

Comment: How do I access these to add code for when the pi boots?

Comment: Any computer Windows/Mac/Linux can see the FAT partitions. You use your normal File Manager and Editor.